# GUI Toolkit/Framework/library for a web-like desktop app in python

Tags: python, windows, user-interface

I was wondering if I could create a desktop app which exhibits seamless tooltip animations, hover animations, click event animations and notification animations like that of a web app.
Till now, I have had some exposure to frontend web technologies and creation of basic GUI apps in tkinter. However, I recently came across the zoom whiteboards desktop app interface which provides smooth animation effects like that of a web app and hence I am curious to know if there is any way to implement the same or achieve a somewhat close result to that.

Below is a small clip of what I am expecting to make (zoom whiteboard interface):-

[image: zoom whiteboard ui recording]

Comment: If it looks a web-app, it usually is. Pretty sure Zoom is built with Electron. Maybe you want somethink like [cefpython](https://pypi.org/project/cefpython3/), [flexx](https://pypi.org/project/flexx/0.3.1/) or [Eel](https://pypi.org/project/Eel/)?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Is there any way in which I can manipulate such behaviour using a module/framework/library using tkinter, pyqt or anything as such in python (without using any web technologies)?